# HOC component - array return true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a mental block right now, I have a HOC component that's checking for a feature flag like below:

```
const withEnabledFeatures = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
      class WithEnabledFeatures extends React.Component<any> {
        enabledFeatures = (): Array<string> => {
          if (window === undefined) return [];
          return window.AH.featureFlags;
        }

        isFeatureEnabled = (feature: string): boolean => {
          return this.enabledFeatures.includes(feature);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <WrappedComponent
              enabledFeatures={this.enabledFeatures()}
              isFeatureEnabled={this.isFeatureEnabled}
              {...this.props}
            />
          )
        }
      }
  };

export default withEnabledFeatures;
```

And I will use this as a prop in another component say

`isFeatureEnabled('feature_a');`

Which will return true if it exists or false if not.

My question is my `isFeatureEnabled` function correct?

Comment: Inside the `HOC` you forgot to `return WithEnabledFeatures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you are not calling `this.enabledFeatures` as a method, you are trying to access a member on it. Use `this.enabledFeatures().` Also, the HOC factory method is not returning the extended class.

```
const withEnabledFeatures = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
      return class WithEnabledFeatures extends React.Component<any> {
        enabledFeatures = (): Array<string> => 
            (window === void 0) ? [] : window.AH.featureFlags;

        isFeatureEnabled = (feature: string): boolean => 
            this.enabledFeatures().includes(feature); // <-- Here, ()

        render() {
          return (
            <WrappedComponent
              enabledFeatures={this.enabledFeatures()}
              isFeatureEnabled={this.isFeatureEnabled}
              {...this.props}
            />
          )
        }
      }
  };

export default withEnabledFeatures;
```

(I also optionally compressed your code and added a best practice, `void 0`)

Answer (score 0):

Added return inside `HOC` for `WithEnabledFeatures` as well as corrected the `isFeatureEnabled` return statement

```
const withEnabledFeatures = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
      return class WithEnabledFeatures extends React.Component<any> {
        enabledFeatures = (): Array<string> => {
          if (window === undefined) return [];
          return window.AH.featureFlags;
        }

        isFeatureEnabled = (feature: string): boolean => {
          return this.enabledFeatures().includes(feature);
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <WrappedComponent
              enabledFeatures={this.enabledFeatures()}
              isFeatureEnabled={this.isFeatureEnabled}
              {...this.props}
            />
          )
        }
      }
  };

export default withEnabledFeatures;
```